# How do I sweep specific columns with dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

An incredibly common operation for my type of data is applying a normalisation factor to all columns. This can be done efficiently using `sweep` or `scale`:

```
normalized = scale(data, center = FALSE, scale = factors)
# or
normalized = sweep(data, 2, factors, `/`)
```

Where

```
data = structure(list(A = c(3L, 174L, 6L, 1377L, 537L, 173L),
    B = c(1L, 128L, 2L, 1019L, 424L, 139L),
    C = c(3L, 66L, 2L, 250L, 129L, 40L),
    D = c(4L, 57L, 4L, 251L, 124L, 38L)),
    .Names = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
    class = c("tbl_df", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L))

factors = c(A = 1, B = 1.2, C = 0.8, D = 0.75)
```

However, how do I do this with dplyr, when my data has additional columns in front? I can do it in separate statements, but I’d like doing it in *one* pipeline. This is my data:

```
data = structure(list(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
    Type = c("X", "X", "X", "Y", "Y", "Y"),
    A = c(3L, 174L, 6L, 1377L, 537L, 173L),
    B = c(1L, 128L, 2L, 1019L, 424L, 139L),
    C = c(3L, 66L, 2L, 250L, 129L, 40L),
    D = c(4L, 57L, 4L, 251L, 124L, 38L)),
    .Names = c("ID", "Type", "A", "B", "C", "D"),
    class = c("tbl_df", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

And I’d like to mutate the data columns without touching the first two columns. Normally I can do this with `mutate_each`; however, how I cannot pass my normalisation factors to that function:

```
data %>% mutate_each(funs(. / factors), A:D)
```

This, unsurprisingly, assumes that I want to divide *each column* by `factors`, rather than each column by its matching factor.

Comment: Perhaps this helps `data %>% list(as.list(factors)) %>% Reduce(`/`, .)`

Comment: @akrun No, that doesn’t work at all.

Comment: My solution was based on your first dataset

Comment: Hm. I think I misunderstood `mutate_each` completely, and it cannot be used to solve this problem at all.

Comment: For the second case `cbind(data[1:2],data %>% select(A:D) %>% list(as.list(factors)) %>% Reduce('/', .))`

Comment: I did the following experiment. I created a df for `factors` and tried `mutate_each`. The outcome seems fine. But, I guess this is not what you are after. `factors <- data.frame(A = 1, B = 1.2, C = 0.8, D = 0.75); mutate_each(data, funs(. / factors$.), A:D)`

Comment: @jazzurro That looks promising.

Comment: @akrun This was purely experimental. But it seems that this is working. If I try to follow the suggested way in the question, this may be one of the close ways.

Comment: @jazzurro I guess you should post it.  I am taking notes on this approach :-)

Comment: @akrun If you say so, I am happy to do that. I am just scared of posting an answer for this type of question...

Comment: @akrun Mission done. :)

Comment: Another option, though not as efficient and succinct as the answer by jazzuro is to use `do` as in `data %>% do(data.frame(.[1:2], sweep(.[-c(1:2)], 2, factors, `/`)))`

Comment: Can you please file an issue on github?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `dplyr 1.0.0`, you can do:

```
data %>%
 rowwise() %>%
 mutate(across(A:D)/factors)

     ID Type      A       B      C      D
  <dbl> <chr> <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1     1 X         3   0.833   3.75   5.33
2     2 X       174 107.     82.5   76   
3     3 X         6   1.67    2.5    5.33
4     4 Y      1377 849.    312.   335.  
5     5 Y       537 353.    161.   165.  
6     6 Y       173 116.     50     50.7
```

Comment: Yup, well spotted. dplyr 1.0.0 filled many (though not all) outstanding gaps in its API to replace base data.frame functionality almost completely.

Answer (score 12):

Given akrun's encouragement, let me post what I did as an answer here. I just intuitively thought that you might want to ask R to indicate columns with a same name to do this `mutate_each`. For instance, if `.` indicates the column, `A`, I thought another column named `A` from another data.frame might be something `dplyr` might like. So, I created a data frame for `factors` then used `mutate_each`. It seems that the outcome is right. Since I have no technical background, I am afraid that I cannot really provide any explanation. I hope you do not mind that.

```
factors <- data.frame(A = 1, B = 1.2, C = 0.8, D = 0.75)

mutate_at(data, vars(A:D), funs(. / foo$.))

# By the time I answered this question, the following was working.
# But mutate_each() is now deprecated.

# mutate_each(data, funs(. / factors$.), A:D)

#  ID Type    A           B      C          D
#1  1    X    3   0.8333333   3.75   5.333333
#2  2    X  174 106.6666667  82.50  76.000000
#3  3    X    6   1.6666667   2.50   5.333333
#4  4    Y 1377 849.1666667 312.50 334.666667
#5  5    Y  537 353.3333333 161.25 165.333333
#6  6    Y  173 115.8333333  50.00  50.666667
```

EDIT

This also works. Given data frame is a special case of list, this is not perhaps surprising.

```
# Experiment
foo <- list(A = 1, B = 1.2, C = 0.8, D = 0.75)

mutate_at(data, vars(A:D), funs(. / foo$.))

# mutate_each(data, funs(. / foo$.), A:D)

#  ID Type    A           B      C          D
#1  1    X    3   0.8333333   3.75   5.333333
#2  2    X  174 106.6666667  82.50  76.000000
#3  3    X    6   1.6666667   2.50   5.333333
#4  4    Y 1377 849.1666667 312.50 334.666667
#5  5    Y  537 353.3333333 161.25 165.333333
#6  6    Y  173 115.8333333  50.00  50.666667
```

Comment: This is what I want. However, I find it utterly confusing and unintuitive. This is a terrible API – the opposite of what dplyr aspires to be.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I am glad to hear that this is what you are after. I understand your frustration. I was initially doing something totally different. Then, I just wanted to be "foolish" a bit and see what happens. I guess this suggests that the API is not necessarily intuitive to a wide range of users. By the way, I learned something new from your question. Thank you very much.

Comment: @KonradRudolph this is how I'd do this using `data.table` - `setDT(data)[, names(factors) := Map("/", .SD, factors), .SDcols = names(factors)]` - not sure if that would clear your intuitiveness bar.

Comment: @jazzurro  Is there a way to do this with `mutate_at`?  I've tried to substitute and it doesn't work. Looks like `mutate_each` will be deprecated.

Comment: @EricKrantz You gotta learn how to use the function. I updated my answer. Have a look.