# Subtracting mean of certain rows using summarise_each

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data set with 30 variables. One of them is an indicator variable (0 or 1), and I would like to subtract the mean of those rows where the label is 1 for certain columns (Something like centering but taking the mean of certain rows instead of the entire column).

```
Col2 Col3 Col4 label
400  322  345  1    
131  345  809  1     
565  676  311  0    
121  645  777  0    
322  534  263  0    
545  222  111  0
```

For the above dataset, I would like to perform the following operation for `Col2:Col4`:

```
x(i,j)-x'(,j)
```

where `x(i,j)` represents a cell, and `x'(,j)` represents the mean of the rows in the column for which `label=1`. For e.g, for `[3,1]` it should be

`(565-mean(400,131))= 299.5`

Expected output for Column 2:

```
Col2
134.5
-134.5
299.5
-144.5
56.5
279.5
```

I have been trying to use the `summarise_each` command but have been unsuccessful till now. The command I'm giving is

```
try<- group_by(data,lbl) %>% select(c(4,13:26)) %>% summarise_each(funs((.)-(mean(data[data$lbl==1,])))
```

But this is generating `NA` and I'm not really sure where I'm going wrong (I'm sure it's in the `summarise_each` command where I'm not able to figure out how to use `funs()` correctly)

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: @ProcrastinatusMaximus  I have edited the question and I hope this makes it clearer. Thanks!

Comment: You want the mean of the columns but without values where `label == 1` ?

Comment: @StevenBeaupré No, for each column I want to subtract the mean of rows for which label==1.

Comment: So the sum of the column (excluding value where `label == 1`) minus the mean of the values where `label == 1` ? Please provide your expected output.

Comment: @StevenBeaupré I've made an edit showing the expected output for Col2.

Comment: I understand. I'll give it a shot when I get home.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
dat %>% 
  mutate_each(funs(. - mean(.[label==1])), -label)
```

> ```
>     Col2   Col3 Col4 label
> 1  134.5  -11.5 -232     1
> 2 -134.5   11.5  232     1
> 3  299.5  342.5 -266     0
> 4 -144.5  311.5  200     0
> 5   56.5  200.5 -314     0
> 6  279.5 -111.5 -466     0
> ```

Comment: Woah. Touché ! Very clever approach.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do it:

```
sweep(df[1:3], 2, colMeans(df[df$label == 1,][1:3]))
```

Which gives:

```
#    Col2   Col3 Col4
#1  134.5  -11.5 -232
#2 -134.5   11.5  232
#3  299.5  342.5 -266
#4 -144.5  311.5  200
#5   56.5  200.5 -314
#6  279.5 -111.5 -466
```

---

Another approach (admittedly more convoluted):

```
library(purrr)

df %>%
  by_row(function(x) {
    x[1:3] - df %>%
      filter(label == 1) %>%
      summarise_each(funs(mean), -label) },
    .collate = "cols",
    .labels = FALSE
  )
```

---

And perhaps the most `dplyr`-esque method (inspired by this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28298688/how-do-i-sweep-specific-columns-with-dplyr/28299858)):

```
cm <- df %>%
  filter(label == 1) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(mean), -label) 

df %>% 
  mutate_each(funs(. - cm$. ), -label)
```

Which gives:

```
#    Col2   Col3 Col4 label
#1  134.5  -11.5 -232     1
#2 -134.5   11.5  232     1
#3  299.5  342.5 -266     0
#4 -144.5  311.5  200     0
#5   56.5  200.5 -314     0
#6  279.5 -111.5 -466     0
```