# using functionals with variable obtained from local environment in R (a lexical scoping issue)

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr, rlang

I'm working on a classification-type problem using some simulations, and I want to count the number of true positives, false positives, etc. using different thresholds.
For example, consider the following example:

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(23)
n <- 100
df <- tibble(
  class = sample(LETTERS[1:5], 100, replace = TRUE),
  pred_class = sample(LETTERS[1:5], 100, replace = TRUE),
  correct = class == pred_class,
  pval = runif(100, 0, 1)
) %>% 
  print()
#> # A tibble: 100 x 4
#>    class pred_class correct   pval
#>    <chr> <chr>      <lgl>    <dbl>
#>  1 C     E          FALSE   0.643 
#>  2 B     C          FALSE   0.561 
#>  3 B     C          FALSE   0.824 
#>  4 D     A          FALSE   0.971 
#>  5 E     A          FALSE   0.0283
#>  6 C     D          FALSE   0.723 
#>  7 E     D          FALSE   0.521 
#>  8 E     D          FALSE   0.619 
#>  9 E     E          TRUE    0.198 
#> 10 E     B          FALSE   0.386 
#> # ... with 90 more rows
```

For a fixed cut-off, the task is trivial (please ignore the direction of the assignments, they are correct for the actual task I'm working on, but I do recognize they might appear backwards here).  This is what I'm trying to accomplish, but with more than 1 cutoff:

```r
df %>%
  summarize(
    cutoff = 0.05,
    TP = sum(!correct & pval < 0.05),
    FP = sum(correct & pval < 0.05),
    FN = sum(!correct & pval >= 0.05),
    TN = sum(correct & pval >= 0.05)
  )
#> # A tibble: 1 x 5
#>   cutoff    TP    FP    FN    TN
#>    <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#> 1   0.05     5     1    73    21
```

But for multiple cutoffs, say `a <- c(0.01, 0.05, 0.1)` or `a <- seq(0, .15, 0.01)`, this is a lot of cut and paste.
So my goal is to figure out how to do this with functionals and (I think?) `summarize_at`.
Unfortunately, this is giving me issues.

I can get this to work when the sums are based on single variables.  It's ugly, but the following works:

```r
# define the functionals (note only 2 since we are only looking at 1 variable)

a <- c(0.01, 0.05, 0.1)
pfun <- list(
  less_p = function(a) {function(p) sum(p < a)},
  more_p = function(a) {function(p) sum(p >= a)}
) %>%
  imap(~list(f = .x, label = .y))

fun_list <- cross(list(alpha = alpha, f = pfun)) %>% map(function(x) {
  list(
    f = x$f$f(x$alpha),
    label = paste(x$f$label, x$alpha, sep = "_")
  )
}) %>%
  set_names(., map_chr(., ~ .x$label)) %>%
  map(~ .x$f)

df %>%
  summarize_at(
    .vars = vars(pval),
    .funs = funs(!!!fun_list)
  )
#> # A tibble: 1 x 10
#>   less_p_0.01 less_p_0.02 less_p_0.03 less_p_0.04 less_p_0.05 more_p_0.01
#>         <int>       <int>       <int>       <int>       <int>       <int>
#> 1           1           3           4           4           6          99
#> # ... with 4 more variables: more_p_0.02 <int>, more_p_0.03 <int>,
#> #   more_p_0.04 <int>, more_p_0.05 <int>
```

Some `gather`, `separate` and `spread` fun, and this will be in the desired format.

However, when we write the functionals using the variable `correct` too, it breaks because `correct` isn't found:

```r
afun <- list(
  TP_fun = function(a) { function(p) sum(!correct & p <  a)},
  FP_fun = function(a) { function(p) sum( correct & p <  a)},
  FN_fun = function(a) { function(p) sum(!correct & p >= a)},
  TN_fun = function(a) { function(p) sum( correct & p >= a)}
) %>%
  imap(~list(f = .x, label = .y))

# all combinations of alpha and the functions
fun_list <- cross(list(alpha = alpha, f = afun)) %>% map(function(x) {
  list(
    f = x$f$f(x$alpha),
    label = paste(x$f$label, x$alpha, sep = "_")
  )
}) %>%
  set_names(., map_chr(., ~ .x$label)) %>%
  map(~ .x$f)


df %>%
  summarize_at(
    .vars = vars(pval),
    .funs = funs(!!!fun_list)
  )
#> Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots): Evaluation error: object 'correct' not found.
```

I tried replacing `correct` in the functionals with `.$correct`, but this does not solve the problem.  What is the best way to reference additional variables from within the functional?

As an aside - I feel like there should be a simpler solution to this problem.  If I'm over-complicating a simple problem, please feel free to

<sup>Created on 2019-01-30  by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: I asked a similar question a couple months ago and got really good answers that might help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53288100/5325862

Comment: Thank you!  that got me what I needed.  end result is `map_df(
  fun_list,
  function(f, data) {
    f(data$pval, data$correct)
  },
  data = df
)`