# How to create a function that truncates a subset of data frame columns based on a list of field length values in R?

Tags: r

I have a data frame in which some of the fields need to be truncated to different lengths. Here is a sample data:

```
library(dplyr)

id <- c(1111, 2222, 3333, 4444, 5555)
first_name <- c("Jonathan", "Sally", "Courtney", "Stephen", "Matthew")
last_name <- c("Johnson", "Montgomery", "Cunningham", "Stephenson", "Matthews")
Height <- c(200, 160, 170, 180, 190)
 
df <- data.frame(id, first_name, last_name, Height, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I want to truncate `first_name` and `last_name` columns to the corresponding lengths of `3` and `5`. I created a simple function that accepts a data frame, field name and field length.

```
truncate_fields <- function(df, field, n) {
  df_tr <-
    mutate(df, {{field}} := str_trunc({{field}}, n, ellipsis = ""))
  return(df_tr)
}
```

The function works great. I now want to apply it to a subset of columns using a list of lengths.

```
fields <- c("first_name", "last_name")
lengths <- c(3, 5)

for(i in 1:length(fields)) {
  df <-
    truncate_fields(df, noquote(fields)[i], lengths[i])
}
```

However I get the following error:

```
Error in `splice()`:
! The LHS of `:=` must be a string or a symbol
```

I also tried `lapply` and `mapply` without much success. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Update:

Using an older version of dplyr (0.7.4.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would also add that you can use existing tools to do this without reassigning the data frame in multiple loops, in fact you do not even need a function if all you are doing is `str_trunc`:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(across(all_of(fields), ~ str_trunc(.x, lengths[fields == cur_column()])))
```

`across` will apply a function over a set of columns. As it iterates of the columns you can access the current iteration column name with `cur_column` to match the index in `fields` and use that index to pull the appropriate value from `lengths`.

**Update**

Given you are using older versions of `dplyr` I think a clean solution uses the `purrr` package (this should work for old versions of `purrr` too):

```
library(purrr)

# named vector is important for use in imap
names(lengths) <- fields

lexprs <- imap(width, ~ expr(str_trunc(!!sym(.y) , width = !!.x)))

df %>% 
  mutate(!!! lexprs)
```

This creates a list of expressions which you can view by looking at `lexpr`. Then within mutate, you can use the split-slice `!!!` operator to unpack this to be evaluated. This only works because `lexprs` carries forward the names from the named vector:

```
rlang::qq_show(
  df %>% 
    mutate(!!! lexprs)
)
df %>% mutate(first_name = str_trunc(first_name, width = 4), last_name = str_trunc(
  last_name, width = 5))
```

**Update 2**

From this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53302133/6382434) question, you can use the global assignment operator `<<-` as long as `fields` and `lengths` are in the same order:

```
i <- 0
df %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(fields), ~ str_trunc(.x, width = lengths[i <<- i + 1]))
```

Comment: looks like I'm locked into an older version of `dplyr` that doesn't have `across()` and `all_of()`. How can this be accomplished with the old school `mutate_()`?

Comment: @Annabanana that depends on what version of `dplyr` you are using. This sort of information would be important to add to your question.

Comment: I agree. The version I have in production is `0.7.4`.

Comment: I updated the question. Please let me know if you can think of a solution using an older version of dplyr that does not have `across()` and `all_of()`.

Comment: @Annabanana I have updated my answer with a proposed solution.

Comment: Don't have `purrr()` unfortunately.

Comment: @Annabanana okay I have updated it again.

Comment: possible to use `lapply()` instead?

Comment: You should check out `mapply` instead.

Answer (score 2):

The `noquote` function only affects how string values are printed the the console. `noquote("variable")` is very different from just `variable`. If you want to turn a string into a symbol, you can use `rlang::sym` and inject that into the calling expression with `!!`. So the following will work

```
for(i in 1:length(fields)) {
  df <-
    truncate_fields(df, !!rlang::sym((fields)[i]), lengths[i])
}
```

and that will be logically equivalent to

```
df <- truncate_fields(df, first_name, 3)
df <- truncate_fields(df, last_name, 5)
```

Comment: Your solution worked beautifully in my dev environment. Unfortunately, I am stuck with an older package versions in production. I'm still getting an error that LHS must be a name or string. Any thoughts on how to overcome this using dplyr 0.7.4.? Perhaps using `mutate_()`.